# Intel MKL ERROR: incorrect parameter when calling gemm()

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, intel-mkl, sycl, cblas

I have this code:

```
void my_function(double *image_vector, double *endmembers, double *abundanceVector, int it, int lines, int samples, int bands, int targets)
{
    double *h_Num;
    double *h_aux;
    double *h_Den;
    int lines_samples = lines*samples;
        
    h_Num = (double*) malloc(lines_samples * targets * sizeof(double));
    h_aux = (double*) malloc(lines_samples * bands * sizeof(double));
    h_Den = (double*) malloc(lines_samples * targets * sizeof(double));

    sycl::queue my_queue{sycl::default_selector{}};

        std::cout << "Device: "
                  << my_queue.get_device().get_info<sycl::info::device::name>()
                  << std::endl;
    
    // USM declaration
    double* image_vector_usm = sycl::malloc_shared<double>(lines_samples*bands, my_queue);
    double* endmembers_usm = sycl::malloc_shared<double>(targets*bands, my_queue);
    double* abundanceVector_usm = sycl::malloc_shared<double>(lines_samples*targets, my_queue); 
    double* h_Num_usm = sycl::malloc_shared<double>(lines_samples*targets, my_queue);
    double* h_aux_usm = sycl::malloc_shared<double>(lines_samples*bands, my_queue);
    double* h_Den_usm = sycl::malloc_shared<double>(lines_samples*targets, my_queue);
    auto nonTrans = oneapi::mkl::transpose::nontrans;
    auto yesTrans = oneapi::mkl::transpose::trans;
    
    int i,j;
    
    // We copy the parameters values into the USM variables // Maybe the mistake is here?
    std::memcpy(image_vector_usm, image_vector,sizeof(double) * lines_samples*bands);
    std::memcpy(endmembers_usm, endmembers,sizeof(double) * targets*bands);
    
    // Initialization
    for(i=0; i<lines_samples*targets; i++)
        abundanceVector_usm[i]=1;

    double alpha = 1.0;
    double beta = 0.0;

    // Start of callings to dgemm()

      oneapi::mkl::blas::row_major::gemm(my_queue, nonTrans, yesTrans, lines_samples, targets, bands, alpha, image_vector_usm,lines_samples, endmembers_usm, targets, beta, h_Num_usm, lines_samples);

    my_queue.wait_and_throw();

    for(i=0; i<it; i++)
    { 
        oneapi::mkl::blas::row_major::gemm(my_queue, nonTrans, nonTrans, lines_samples, targets, bands, alpha, abundanceVector_usm, lines_samples, endmembers_usm, targets, beta, h_aux_usm, lines_samples);
        
        my_queue.wait_and_throw();

        oneapi::mkl::blas::row_major::gemm(my_queue, nonTrans, yesTrans, lines_samples, targets, bands, alpha,h_aux_usm, lines_samples, endmembers_usm, targets, beta, h_Den_usm, lines_samples);

        my_queue.wait_and_throw();

        my_queue.parallel_for(sycl::range<1> (lines_samples*targets), [=] (sycl::id<1> j){
            abundanceVector_usm[j] = abundanceVector_usm[j]*(h_Num_usm[j]/h_Den_usm[j]);
        }).wait();
    }

    free(h_Den);
    free(h_Num);
    free(h_aux);
    
    // Free SYCL
    free(image_vector_usm, my_queue);
    free(endmembers_usm, my_queue);
    free(abundanceVector_usm, my_queue);
    free(h_Num_usm, my_queue);
    free(h_aux_usm, my_queue);
    free(h_Den_usm, my_queue);
}
```

This is the makefile, I've borrowed it from a default oneMKL example called "matrix_mul_mkl" and adapted it to my file name. The makefile is called GNUmakefile:

```
# Makefile for GNU Make

default: run

all: run

run: my_code

MKL_COPTS = -DMKL_ILP64  -I"${MKLROOT}/include"
MKL_LIBS = -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_sycl -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lsycl -lOpenCL -lpthread -lm -ldl

DPCPP_OPTS = $(MKL_COPTS) -fsycl-device-code-split=per_kernel $(MKL_LIBS)

my_code: my_code.cpp RS_algorithm.cpp # This RS file is also needed to compile, nothing strange there I believe, completely sequential and just calls the function in my_code.
    dpcpp $^ -o $@ $(DPCPP_OPTS)


clean:
    -rm -f my_code

.PHONY: clean run all
```

I know that sometimes there are troubles with the ILP64 or LP64 libraries, but the matrix_mul example mentioned above works, so that can't be right?

And this is what the execution returns:

```
Device: Intel whatever model...
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 11 was incorrect on entry to cblas_dgemm.
Segmentation fault.
```

I have put some prints right under the calls to gemm() and done some tests; the first call seems to execute, but not the second one.

I have tried and checked everything, what is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error message already indicates where to look (`Parameter 11`). You might want to print all arguments passed to `cgemm` and triple check that they are all consistent. Also: The second invocation of `gemm` uses a different transpose mode (`N,T`) than the first one (`N,N`). Transpose modes have implications for the leading dimension of the affected matrix (see documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using the row_major version of the gemm call, and I had to call the column_major version for this code, be careful!

Answer (score 1):

By default most of the compilers take integers ( 'int' for C or C++ / 'INTEGER' for Fortran) as 32-bit length. So most applications need to be linked with LP64 MKL libraries.
(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/linking-your-application-with-onemkl/linking-in-detail/linking-with-interface-libraries/using-the-ilp64-interface-vs-lp64-interface.html)

So try linking against LP64 interface and see if it works.
Additionally, I would suggest you set MKL_VERBOSE=1
(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/managing-output/using-onemkl-verbose-mode.html)
and then run your code so that you can see what parameters are passed to the function (as your error message says so).

You can also refer to the examples which comes with oneMKL.There is a similar example  under the mkl directory location in your system as below \oneAPI\mkl\2022.0.2\examples\examples_dpcpp\dpcpp\blas\source with usm_gemm.cpp
file name which I presume should help you.